# ionic scrolling not working in ios, but with ion-scroll it is working with android (pixel) phone

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework

**ionic.min.css  -->    Ionic, v1.3.2**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/ionic/css/ionic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/mobiscroll.custom/css/mobiscroll.custom-3.0.0-beta6.min.css">
```

I have a new module I made and I thought I had everything I needed and then when iphone developers told me, I thought I fixed with adding in

```
<ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" style="height: 900px;">
```

But that only worked with my google android pixel and so i try to fix mostly with trial and error from google searches.

```
<ion-view view-title="Home Consumer">
<ion-content >
<ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" style="height: 900px;">

  <ion-list class="list-borderless">
    <ion-item>
      Please Confirm the following:<br><br>
      <h2 style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Account Details</strong></h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list >
    <ion-item >
      <div>
        Name: {{vmHome.account[0].authorizationFirstName}} {{vmHome.account[0].authorizationLastName}}
      </div>
      <div>
        Phone Number: {{vmHome.account[0].btn}}
      </div>
      <div>
        Relationship: {{vmHome.account[0].relation}}
      </div>
      <div><strong>Service Address:</strong>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{vmHome.account[0].serviceAddress}}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{vmHome.account[0].serviceCity}}, {{vmHome.account[0].serviceState}} {{vmHome.account[0].serviceZip}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Order Details:</strong>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="accountType in vmHome.account">
        {{accountType.utilityTypeName}} Acct#: {{accountType.accountNumber}}
      </div>
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Program Details:</strong>
      </div>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list >
    <ion-item >

      <div ng-repeat="account in vmHome.account">
        <div> <strong>{{account.utilityTypeName}}</strong></div>
        <div> {{account.programName}} </div>
        <div> Rate: {{account.rate}}</div>
        <div>Term (months): {{account.term}}</div>
        <div> MSF: {{account.msf | currency}}</div>
        <div> ETF: {{account.etf | currency}}</div>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list >
    <ion-item >

      <button ng-click="vmHome.newEnrollment()">
    Next</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Tom are you trying this on a simulator ?

Comment: I'm trying with Ionic serve with chrome and emulator of phone ,  but then I publish it to web server and then test it on Android phone and Iphone 6

Comment: can I get a sample of a complete independent working code ?

Comment: sometimes the issue might be with your css not ionic